# Magento 2 add extra field to account registration

Tags: magento2, module, forms

I'm trying to add another field to the customer create form.

So far I have the following in my new module folder:

**Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
        namespace tivol\registrationExtra\Setup;
        use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
        use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
        class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
        {
            /**
             * Customer setup factory
             *
             * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
             */
            private $customerSetupFactory;
            /**
             * Init
             *
             * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
             */
            public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
            {
                $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            }
            /**
             * Installs DB schema for a module
             *
             * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
             * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
             * @return void
             */
            public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
            {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "salesAssociate",  array(
                "type"     => "varchar",
                "backend"  => "",
                "label"    => "Sales associate",
                "input"    => "string",
                "source"   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource',
                "visible"  => true,
                "required" => false,
                "default" => "",
                "frontend" => "",
                "unique"     => false,
                "note"       => ""

            ));

            $salesAssociate   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "salesAssociate");

            $salesAssociate = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'salesAssociate');
            $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
            $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
            $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
            /* $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit"; */
            $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
            $salesAssociate->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100);
            $salesAssociate->save();

            $installer->endSetup();
        }
        }
```

**view/frontend/layout/customer_registration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                <body>
                    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sales_associate" template="MyModules_CustomerMarketingFields::salesassociate.phtml"/>
                    </referenceContainer>
                </body></page>
```

**view/frontend/templates/salesassociate.phtml**

```
            <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('If you shop in-store who is your regular sales associate') ?></span>
                    </legend>


        <div class="field">
            <label for="associate" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Associate') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="regulation" id="associate" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Associate') ?>" >
                <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'tivol_registrationExtra',
__DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
                <module name="tivol_registrationExtra" setup_version="0.0.1" />
            </config>
```

Noting shows up in the frontend and backend says "page isn't working"

Any ideas as to what I have done wrong?

Comment: Which is the message? Or only  `"page isn't working` message?

Comment: Page isn't working is the mrssage

Answer (score 1):

Page not working or Page not found error due **ACL** missing in your module. Check **Acl** for **custom module**.

**`InstallData.php`** : add custom text field in backend.

```
<?php 
              namespace Paarth\CustomerAttribute\Setup;
              use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
              use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
              use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

              class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
              {
                private $customerSetupFactory;


                        public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
                        {
                          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
                        }

                        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface
                        $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
                        {
                        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */

                        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
                        $setup->startSetup();

                         $attributeCode = "custom_text";

                         $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);


                        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer',
                        'custom_text', [
                        'label' => 'Custom Text',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'frontend_input' => 'text',
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                         'system'=> 0,
                        'position' => 105,
                        ]);

                $loyaltyAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_text');
                $loyaltyAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',['adminhtml_customer']);
                $loyaltyAttribute->save();

            $setup->endSetup(); }} 
?>
```